# java code to get chat history between two users using smack api from openfire server

Tags: java, chat, openfire, smack

I am new to Smack API and i want retrieve chat history b/w 2 users from openfire xmpp server. For this, is it required to add any extra plugin or change of any settings required in open fire? Pls somebody share some sample java code to retrieve chat transcript between two users.
  Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By installing Open Archive plugin in the Openfire server you can see the chat conversation between two user from the Openfire admin panel which is pretty easy and that is web based too.
But if you want to retrieve the chat history from SMACK client, then remember neither XEP-313: Message Archive Management nor XEP-0136 Archive Messaging are currently implemented in Smack.